# Determine whether or not an array has element, Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have the following json:

```json
{
  "a":[1,2,3,4],
  "b":[]
}
```

I want to know whether or not the array has elements or not.
Thus the desired output required is:

```json
{
  "a":[1,2,3,4],
  "b":[],
  "is_element_in_a":True,
  "is_element_in_b":False    
}
```

What will be the jolt spec expression for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **modify-overwrite-beta** transformation spec along with **size** function in order to determine the size of the list is whether *zero* or *not* in the first step, and then use a **shift** transformation spec to print the *boolean* values within a conditional logic such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "in_a": "=size(@(1,a))",
      "in_b": "=size(@(1,b))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "in_*": {
        "0": {
          "#False": "is_element_&2"
        },
        "*": {
          "#True": "is_element_&2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```